# How can I get firebase data as Querysnapshot?

Tags: arrays, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to get Array from firebase as a Querysnaoshot from flutter but how can I do that ?
This is the code

```
class Videos {
  final String allhashtagsofeveryvideo;
  final String categorie;
  final String commentcount;
  final String hashtag1;
  final String hashtag2;
  final String hashtag3;
  final String likes;
  final String previewimage;
   final String profilepic;
  final String sharecount;
  final String uid;
  final String username;
  final String videourl;

  Videos( {this.allhashtagsofeveryvideo,this.commentcount, this.hashtag1, this.hashtag2, this.hashtag3, this.likes, this.previewimage, this.profilepic, this.sharecount, this.uid, this.videourl, this.categorie, this.username});
}

 Videos videosfromsnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return Videos(
      categorie: snapshot.data()['categorie'],
      commentcount: snapshot.data()['commentcount'].toString(),
      hashtag1: snapshot.data()['hashtag1'],
      hashtag2: snapshot.data()['hashtag2'],
      hashtag3: snapshot.data()['hashtag3'],
      likes:snapshot.data()['likes'].length.toString(),
      previewimage: snapshot.data()['previewimage'],
      profilepic: snapshot.data()['profilepic'],
      sharecount: snapshot.data()['sharecount'].toString(),
      uid: snapshot.data()['uid'],
      allhashtagsofeveryvideo:snapshot.data()['Hashtagsforallvideos'],
      username: snapshot.data()['username'],
      videourl: snapshot.data()['videourl'],
    );
  }
 var firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> _allResults = [];

    QuerySnapshot snapshots = await firestore.collection('videos').get();
    for (var doc in snapshots.docs) {
     
      _allResults.addAll(doc.data()["Hashtagsforallvideos"]);
```

Maybe I should map over it or something like that ?
So instead of adding it like you seeing I wanna use like that

```
 QuerySnapshot snapshots = await firestore.collection('videos').get();
    for (var doc in snapshots.docs) {

....
 _allResults= qn.docs
```

But how can I do this maybe anyone can help
No im getting this error

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot'
#0      _OpenallsinglehashtagsState.getusers
package:wichtigdenyady/homesearchingall/openalldocs.dart:90
<asynchronous suspension>
```

And the line is this one

```
 _allResults.addAll(doc.data()["Hashtagsforallvideos"]);
```

Probably something like that

```
  var firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot qn = await firestore.collection('videos').get();
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _allResults = qn.docs;
    });
```

Comment: Your `snapshots` is a `QuerySnapshot` as far as I can tell. What doesn't work about it?

Comment: Ok frank probably I got the problem the problem is that data() is dynamic because of that im getting this error [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot'
. Please check my code so you can see where the error throws, Maybe you now any solution for that .

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit hard withot the data but I hope this can help you:

```dart
Future<List<QueryDocumentSnapshot>> getVideos() async {
  List<String> allVideoHastags = [];
  List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> _allResults = [];

  QuerySnapshot snapshots = await _firestore.collection('videos').get();

  for (QueryDocumentSnapshot videoSnapshot in snapshots.docs) {
    List<String> videoHastags =
        List.from(videoSnapshot.data()['Hashtagsforallvideos']);
    allVideoHastags.addAll(videoHastags);
    _allResults.add(videoSnapshot);
  }

  return _allResults;
}
```

In most cases we miss the `List.from` constructor when we work with `Firestore` arrays and need them in a `List`.

Comment: This looks very good but how can I then do this _allResults= allVideoHastags; When _allResults is a list of QueryDoumentsnapshot. I think that the only one thats left then it should work

Comment: check my post I update it take a look on the latest update I need to use it like that

Comment: If you want a List of `QueryDocumentSnapshot` you can add them directly like so `_allResults.addAll(doc);`

Comment: You mean like this _allResults= allVideoHastags; If so then I tried it says A value of type 'List<String>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<QueryDocumentSnapshot>'. Because your list allVideoHastags is a list of string I just need the docs of it

Comment: I have updated the answer. `_allResults` can be a List of `QueryDocumentSnapshot` but you get then the whole document and not just the hastags. If that is OK for you it should work with the code above.

Comment: I left both variants there so we can see the difference between both aproaches.

Comment: No thats what I dont want thats what im trying I want just the hashtags

Comment: Unfortunately you can't get a `Field` value (in this case an Array Field) as `QueryDocumentSnapshot`. A `QueryDocumentSnapshot` always represents the whole document with all fields. You can eather get all documents as `List<QueryDocumentSnapshot>` or all Hashtags as `List<String>`. Maybe it is enough to change `List<String> _allResults = [];`