# type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot'

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Why im getting this error

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot'
#0      _OpenallsinglehashtagsState.getusers
package:wichtigdenyady/homesearchingall/openalldocs.dart:90
<asynchronous suspension>
```

I dont know actually why im getting  this error  maybe anyone can help
Heres where the error throws

```
  List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> _allResults = [];
 var firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

    QuerySnapshot snapshots = await firestore.collection('videos').get();
    for (var doc in snapshots.docs) {
      _allResults.add(doc.data()["Hashtagsforallvideos"]);
    }
```

I think maybe it comes from data() because this is dynamic? What I trying here is getting the array from firebase that calls Hashtagsforallvideos which every video in videos collection has.

If you need more information please leave a comment
This is my howle code

```
class Openallsinglehashtags extends StatefulWidget {
  static const route = '/Openallsinglehashtags';
  final TextEditingController searchinginput;
  const Openallsinglehashtags({Key key, this.searchinginput}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OpenallsinglehashtagsState createState() => _OpenallsinglehashtagsState();
}

class _OpenallsinglehashtagsState extends State<Openallsinglehashtags> {
  List <QueryDocumentSnapshot>_allResults = [];
  List _resultsList = [];
  Future resultsLoaded;
  bool nosuerfound = false;
  String searchresult;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.searchinginput.addListener(_onsearchChanged);
    setState(() {
      nosuerfound = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.searchinginput.removeListener(_onsearchChanged());

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    widget.searchinginput.text;
    resultsLoaded = getVideos();
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  _onsearchChanged() {
    setState(() {
      nosuerfound = false;
    });
    searchResults();
  }

  searchResults() {
    var showResults = [];
    if (widget.searchinginput.text != "") {
      for (var tripsnapshot in _allResults) {
        var title3 = DatbaseService.instance
            .videosfromsnapshot(tripsnapshot)
            .allhashtagsofeveryvideo
            .toLowerCase();

        if (title3.contains(widget.searchinginput.text.toLowerCase())) {
          setState(() {
            nosuerfound = true;
          });
          showResults.add(tripsnapshot);
        }
      }
    } else {
      setState(() {
        nosuerfound = true;
      });
      showResults = List.from(_allResults);
    }
    setState(() {
      _resultsList = showResults;
    });
  }

Future<List<String>> getVideos() async {
  List<String> allVideoHastags = [];
 var firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  QuerySnapshot snapshots = await firestore.collection('videos').get();

   for (QueryDocumentSnapshot videoSnapshot in snapshots.docs) {
    List<String> videoHastags =
        List.from(videoSnapshot.data()['Hashtagsforallvideos']);
    allVideoHastags.addAll(videoHastags);
  }
  print(allVideoHastags);
_allResults= snapshots.docs;
    searchResults();

  return allVideoHastags;
}

  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<Userforid>(context);
    if (nosuerfound == true) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _resultsList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0), // Add margin
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                NavigationService.instance
                    .navigateToRoute(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                  return Beitragvideo(
                    _resultsList[index].data()['Hashtagsforallvideos'],
                    _resultsList[index].data()['Hashtagsforallvideos'],
                    _resultsList[index].data()['Hashtagsforallvideos'],
                  );
                }));
              },
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  HighlightedMatchesText(
                      searchString: widget.searchinginput.text,
                      content:
                          _resultsList[index].data()['Hashtagsforallvideos']),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    } else {
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 30, 0, 0),
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
              child: Text(
            "No Hashtag found",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
          )),
        ),
```

What I do is I using a searchfield where user can search hashtags. And that hashtags are from the arrays of each video . So what I want is when user typed one hashtags only showing him this hashtags that he enter and not all hashtags of one video and also not all hashtags of the howle list . and if he not searching I just add all hashtags and user can only search in that list if theres no hashtag found then I print no hashtags is found and if any hashtag of that list contains user input I show him these hashtags.  HighlightedMatchesText is just a class where I bold these letters that contains user input .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we dicussed this on another [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67218952/how-can-i-get-firebase-data-as-querysnapshot/67220400?noredirect=1#comment118818101_67220400). It is not possible to accomplishe what you want. A `List<QueryDocumentSnapshot>` representing your hashtags because a `QueryDocumentSnapshot` can only represent a whole firestore document and not just parts/Fields of it.

That means you have 2 options:

1. Get the whole documents in a list and using `QueryDocumentSnapshot` like this:
   (Your can still read the hastags from the snapshots)

```dart
Future<List<QueryDocumentSnapshot>> getVideos() async {
  List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> _allResults = [];

  QuerySnapshot snapshots = await _firestore.collection('videos').get();

  for (QueryDocumentSnapshot videoSnapshot in snapshots.docs) {
    _allResults.add(videoSnapshot);
  }

  return _allResults;
}
```

2. Get a List of Strings having all the hashtags without the `QueryDocumentSnapshot` like this:

```dart
Future<List<String>> getHashtags() async {
  List<String> allVideoHastags = [];

  QuerySnapshot snapshots = await _firestore.collection('videos').get();

  for (QueryDocumentSnapshot videoSnapshot in snapshots.docs) {
    List<String> videoHastags =
        List.from(videoSnapshot.data()['Hashtagsforallvideos']);
    allVideoHastags.addAll(videoHastags);
  }

  return allVideoHastags;
}
```

Comment: Hey Tarik now I understand you answer and I decide to pick the second method . But for that I have to rebuild my code a bit please check out maybe you can help .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67226900/how-can-i-check-if-textoinput-contains-any-string-inside-list

Comment: Great to hear that. I think I know now how you want to solve it. I will write an answer on your next question.

Comment: Brother I soleved it all

Comment: just one small thing I will open a question then you can answer this is very easy I wanna giving you the credits just for you help .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67226900/how-can-i-show-a-listviewbuilder here check it out

Comment: Hey maybe you can check this out its based on your answer.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67230081/how-to-check-if-string-already-exists-in-list

Answer (score 0):

If remember correct from your previous question `Hashtagsforallvideos` was a `List<String>`?

If this is correct then the values being added to the `_allResults` will not be `QueryDocumentSnapshot` as defined by the assignment but rather `String`, hence the error, `_allResults` expects a Firebase `QueryDocumentSnapshot`, but you are adding `Strings` to the List.

Do let me know if this is true.

Comment: Yeah and because of that I ask that question I now that and my question is how can I add a QueryDoucmetnsnapshot doc to the _allResults list thats include my Hashtagsforallvideos

Comment: If this is not possiblee please tell me what should I do do get it like this ?

Comment: @sdfwedasas  It is possible, but is it required? 
As i dont know the whole feature you are developing this makes it hard
to answer your question without making assumptions and StackOverflow may not be the best place to get an answer for a question like this. I would suggest looking through the Firebase docs, Youtube and good old google. If you are  learning to code these are the best places
Please also check the guide below

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

I'm sorry but i don't think I can help you on this one :(

Comment: if I update my post will you maybe check the code so you can see why im needing this ?

Comment: Please check I tied to explain a bit so you can understand my code if any more information needed please leave a comment I will be thankful if you have a solution because I tried to figure out for 1 week and still nobody understand nobody can help

Comment: You don't need the FIrebaseQuery, I simple way is, you can create a list of all the hash tags from the video and use the search to filter the tags you have on the client side. You should be able to do it, if you still have an issue i would suggest breaking up the problem into smaller pieces

Comment: Would you maybe explain a bit better ? So I have first to create a list of the hashtags and then ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231486/discussion-between-rohan-thacker-and-sdfwedasas).

Comment: Hey bro I get the list of string now I ask a new question so you can get your credits if you help . Check out .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67226900/how-can-i-check-if-textoinput-contains-any-string-inside-list