# How to check if string already exists in list?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to create a list of string which has array from firebase . And that works perfectly. But now I wanna filter the list a bit . So what I want is add allhastags one time . So if a hashtags exist twice I wanna just put it int he list once. Heres my code

```
  Future<List<String>> getHashtags() async {
    List<String> allVideoHastags = [];

    QuerySnapshot snapshots =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('videos').get();

    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot videoSnapshot in snapshots.docs) {
      List<String> videoHastags =
          List.from(videoSnapshot.data()['Hashtagsforallvideos']);
      allVideoHastags.addAll(videoHastags);
    }
    _allResults = allVideoHastags;
     searchResults();
   
    return allVideoHastags;
  }
```

So before adding the hashtags into the list ,I wanna check if it already exists in the list of strings .Hope anyone can help .If you need more information please leave a comment

Comment: Not an answer to the specific question, but you might want to consider using array-union to store store the hashtags, which would prevent storing duplicates. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop over the hashtags you get from firebase and add them to your results only if they are not already in there like this:

```dart
Future<List<String>> getHashtags() async {
  List<String> allVideoHastags = [];

  QuerySnapshot snapshots =
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('videos').get();

  for (QueryDocumentSnapshot videoSnapshot in snapshots.docs) {
    List<String> videoHastags =
        List.from(videoSnapshot.data()['Hashtagsforallvideos']);

    videoHastags.forEach((element) {
      if(!allVideoHastags.contains(element)){
          allVideoHastags.add(element);
      }
    });
    
  }
  _allResults = allVideoHastags;
  searchResults();

  return allVideoHastags;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
YOUR_LIST.forEach((element) => if(element == "YOUR_STRING") {YOUR_NEW_LIST.add(element )});
```

Answer (score 0):

This would remove all duplicates from a list

```
    _allResults = allVideoHastags.toSet().toList();
```